# Execution of Hive Query in a Shell Action in Oozie

Tags: shell, hive, oozie

Is it possible to execute a hive query ( a query, that returns a value and it is used in the script) inside a shell script action in Oozie. The hive query is executed using hive -e option. What configurations need to be made in the workflow, if it can be done ?

Thanks..

Comment: You can run an Hive query in the shell script. Just add the hive lib path  using `oozie.action.sharelib.for.shell=hive`.

Comment: And don't forget to ship `hive-site.xml` configuration with a `<file>` instruction...

Answer (score 0):

Your shell action configuration could look like this:

```
  <action name="someaction">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <exec>somescript.sh</exec>
      <env-var>SOME_VARIABLE=1</env-var>
      <file>${someactionScriptPathName}#somescript.sh</file>
      <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="nextaction"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
  </action>
```

Your hive command can be now inside of the somescript.sh script.